# Call to a member function insert() on a non-object Magento

Tags: magento

I am Using Observer Event in my custom module's Config.xml

```
<controller_action_layout_render_before>
                <observers>
                    <Test_Check_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Test_Check_Helper_Data</class>
                        <method>checkValidi</method>
                    </Test_Check_Model_Observer>
                </observers> </controller_action_layout_render_before>
```

Now in Test/Check/Helper/Data checkValidi Method I am inserting a block in Content.

>

```
 class Test_Check_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
>   public function checkValidi($observer) {
>         $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
>         $content = $layout->getBlock('content');
>         $block = 'hello! I am Working';
>         $content->insert($block);
>     }
```

But In Frontend When I am Filling Checkout billing and other information it gives me an Error Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in right side bar of  Your Checkout Progress ,Please Give me any Solution for that Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at layout of checkout module `checkout.xml` you can see that some handles do not have `content` block. Eg, `checkout_onepage_progress_billing` or `checkout_onepage_progress_shipping`

So, you will get `non-object` error with your code. I think you should check $block variable before calling method.

```
      $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
      $content = $layout->getBlock('content');

      if ($content) {
          $block = 'hello! I am Working';
          $content->insert($block);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to call helper from observer.

Observer always call a  model file ,it did not class

i have modify and code config.xml code is

```
<global>
    <models>
        <testcheck>
            <class>Test_Check_Model</class>
        </testcheck>
    </models>
</global>
 <events>

        <controller_action_layout_render_before>
            <observers>
                <test_check_codel_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>testcheck/observer</class>
                    <method>your_function_name</method>
                </test_check_codel_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before>
    </events>
```

And then Create Observer Observer.php file Under app/code/YourcodePoll/Test/Check/Model/

and below
code in Observer.php

is

```
<?php class Test_Check_Model_Observer
{
public function  your_function_name($observer){

  $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
        ->setText('<h1>This is a text block</h1>');
    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 //$observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();


}
}
```